# React native select multiple items like gallery

Tags: react-native, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

We all using some Gallery app in our phones. In gallery when trying to delete photo, we can select multiple images with sliding our fingers.

I do not know the keyword of this,I searched but couldn't find the event or handler.I really want to use this on my app to select multiple component list item.

What is the keyword and how to implement it.Anyone to help ?

[The example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6OPs.png)

This is what I made

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {
         console.log('do',gesture);
      }
   });
```

render

```
{this.state.hours.map((hours, index) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        }}
        {...this.state.panResponder.panHandlers}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}
          onPress={() => {
            this.hoursSelect(hours, index);
          }}>
          <hoursComponent
            hoursText={hours.hoursText}
            isSelected={hours.isSelected}
            hours={hours}
            pushSecilihours={this.pushhours}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  })}
```

[Consolelog and screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNZBM.png)

Ican't get the touched value

This what I need to do.Sliding or touching on over components and get the values.
Thank you.

I can get x y coordinate values but how to use it.

Comment: Can anyone write something

Comment: I can give more detail if you ask me

Comment: Idea is to get the item offset using onLayout method and then use PanHandler to match the value of item layout and current offset value if it matches then mark is as selected.

Comment: last part is easy to set selected but the others. I added some code

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Noop still can't, hard to do this, can't do with coordinates @KatiaChumakova

Comment: @masterAvatarr I have shared my GitHub repo on answer comments. you can pull and check if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can get offset of the elements using the `onLayout` method and then use `PanResponder` to detect the PanResponder GestureState then compare the offSet of current elements and GestureState value if it matches then mark as selected.

For Storing the selected items while sliding through elements, you need to create 2 states,
let's say: `selectedElements` and `gestureSelectionList`

- `selectedElements` to store currently selected items.
- `gestureSelectionList` to track the gesture touch Element while sliding through the elements.
- once the touch gesture is released you need to push the `gestureSelectionList` elements to `selectedElements` and then clear gestureSelectionList so we can again store new elements and repeat the process on the next gesture state.

Sorry if I was unable to explain it clearly.
you can check my GitHub repo where I have done it: https://github.com/sushantdsuwal/DragAndSelectMultipleItems

Comment: is there a demo using `Flatlist` or `ScrollView`?